# Xcode 6.01 iOS Simulator 8.0 has no skin and is too small on Retina Macbook Pro

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6, retina-display

Have just updated to Xcode 6.01 and most things seem to be working. Frustratingly though the simulator has lost its skin, and more importantly has become a lot smaller on my screen.

The skin was convenient to have a home button to press whenever you needed to easily do it, but the rendered size of the simulator doing a iPhone 5 sized display was perfect as I am doing a lot of dev on a train, where the increased size of the device and content was a benefit.

Has anyone had any luck restoring this to how it was?

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard shortcut to press the Home button is ⇧⌘H:

<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>

I agree that it's annoying that the iOS Simulator's physical Home button was removed. However, I've now gotten into the habit of using the keyboard shortcut (which is faster overall).

You can also access the button via the Hardware menu:

[image: Home button via menu.]

Comment: So it's really gone!? :-(

The hotkey is great, although when using the simulator you're using the mouse/trackpad so the home button press was fine too. 

To be honest it's more the fact it's incorrectly making the device really small on my display (I run in a higher than default retina res).

Another issue is the skin is helpful to get your head around which orientation you're running at any one time, upside down or not essentially.

Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

As far as the simulator size goes, you can restore it to 100% by hitting Cmd + 1, or going to "Window > Scale > 100%".

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 100% is not the same size as it used to be before this update.. the iPhone in the simulator used to look oversized alongside having its outer skin, this helped make it easier to read on the train. Now it's probably closer to the right size of a real device but it just feels smaller and harder to read on a moving train.